# Importing Map Styles in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, style, style-manager

I recently found some information on [exporting map styles in arcmap](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/09/28/symbols-and-styles-in-arcgis-10-0/) and I used this to save some specific symbology that I will need to reuse many times.  However, I can't find any documentation or tools on importing the map styles? I have the same exact layers with the same schema, but now I want to apply the same symbology using my exported map styles.

I tried this tool for the first time because it seemed more efficient than saving individual styles or saving layer files. How can I import the map styles back in that I exported? I can import them in as a custom style, but I want them to automatically apply back to the appropriate layers.

Comment: "I have the same exact layers" - If you're wanting the same layers with the same symbology, I think you want to look at exporting to Layer File rather than exporting styles.

Comment: If you're wanting to apply the same symbology to *different* layers though, this can be done using arcpy to import layer symbology

Comment: The layer files are not appropriate for this purpose because they are just a link to another data source, but I am constantly republishing the database and managing between multiple users. The data is being taken offline completely then loaded into the master database.  It is designed to work across the cloud platform without server (to secure data connections to our server)

Comment: @Stella did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @buddiebubba no... I simply did the manual work.